# Getting AutowireViewModel in a ControlTemplate to work

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

In my Xamarin application I use PRISM and on my pages I use the AutowireViewModel support for my viewmodels. 
I'm also using ControlTemplates so I can easy change the look and feel.

```
    <ContentView 
        ControlTemplate="{StaticResource LoginTemplate}">
    </ContentView>
```

But the problem is that I can't get my bindings to work on my contentTempaltes. 
I use TemplateBinding and tried BindigContext.

```
          <Label Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.Text" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0, 30, 0, 0" />
```

I also tried the Parent. but no bindings.

```
          <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.Text" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0, 30, 0, 0" />

          <Label Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.Parent.Text" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0, 30, 0, 0" />

          <Label Text="{Binding BindingContext.Text" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0, 30, 0, 0" />
```

...
If I create a pure viewmodel with just some properties I can bind it when applying the BindingContext element inside my page.xaml

But I want Prism to just set my AutowireViewModel to the BindixContext... 
But how?

I have tried BindixContext="{TemplateBing ..."} as well without any progress.

Best Regards,
Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we add`BindingContext="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext}"`
on the root element in out template we could use ordinary Binding.

So it seems the BindingContext will not be set automatically from the parent. 
Parent and BindingContext is null on our template view.

This seems odd, because if this will work, why can't this be a default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<Label Text="{TemplateBinding MyText}"/>
```

if you have a `MyText` property on your view model...

Comment: Yeah, if i add a label before the "ContentView"-part that can bind to the viewmodel.
Also, the view itself is shown correctly from the LoginTemplate. The only thing not working is bindings inside LoginTemplate